# Return the count of a collection

Tags: python, mongodb

How can I turn `db.collection.count()` into a Python script?

I just want it to return a number.

```
#import json file to MongoDB
logger.info(' Import du fichier .json vers la base MongoDB')
#subprocess.call('mongoimport --db AutoPrivilege -c cars stockvo.json --jsonArray --upsert --drop',shell=True)
p = subprocess.Popen(['mongoimport', '--db', 'myBD', '-c', 'cars', '/opt/data/stockvo.json', '--jsonArray', '--upsert', '--drop'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()

if stdout:
    logger.info(stdout)

if stderr:
    logger.error(stderr)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

you will need to connect to your database and then run the `db.collection.count()` to count the items in your collection in python.

```
import pymongo

# connect to mongodb instance
conn = pymongo.MongoClient('localhost')
# connect to the database
db   = conn['mydb']
# print a count of the items in our collection
print(db.collection.count())
```

Comment: `db.collection.count()` should suffice, no need to `find()`

Comment: agreed.  i pulled that from a snippet of code i had and only cleared out the find condition.  `find()` is only needed if a filter or condition is required.

Comment: @user2569951 FYI, the count() method takes a filter as well: http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.count.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from pymongo import MongoClient

#connect to mongodb instance
connection = MongoClient("localhost")

# connect to the myDB database and the stock collection
db = connection.myDB.stock 

# print out the count
print(db.count())

# close the connection to MongoDB
connection.close()
```